# I cant get any javascript (jQuery) working on iOs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, mobile

I am trying to rebuild my portfolio, and on desktop all js functions works, but when i load my page on a mobile device it seems like all javascript are blocked or something.

I have shortened down my script.js file to contain only this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert("hi");
});
```

And in the bottom of my index.php i have this (i have excluded all php calls, so it is a simple html page with scripts)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/script.js"></script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: everything seems to be ok... Did you tried to open your website through a desktop Safari and checked if console show up something?

Comment: You can also conect your iPhone to the computer and explore it remotely with the developer tools of your desktop Safari.

Comment: Thanks @gabrielperales
I debugged it as you showed below, and found out the path to script.js was not found. Had to exclude the first "/" since i've put the new portfolio structure in a directory on the domain... so... Thanks a lot. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to be ok. You can check if your Safari console show up something with remote debugging:

- Enable 'Web Inspector' on your iOS device. Do this by going to `Settings > Safari > Advanced`, and toggling `Web Inspector` and `JavaScript` to enabled.
  [image: Activate safari debugging]
- Enable `Develop menu` on Safari on your desktop computer. Do this by going to `Safari > Preferences > Advanced` and ticking the check for `Show Develop menu in bar`

[image: Show Develop menu]

- Plug your iOS device to your computer, and in your desktop Safari go to `Develop > [YOUR_DEVICE]` and click on the page you want to debug.

[image]